# ')' expected error with if-else statements, including &&s

Tags: java, if-statement

So I have multiple if-else statements making it so if the user is a m/f and what choice they chose to decide their tdee.

Here is a chunk of the code:

```
    else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
    {
    activityFactor = 1.6;
    }
    else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("F") && (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))    
    {
    activityFactor = 1.5;
    }
```

Comment: are you suggesting women are less active than men? Or vice versa?

Comment: Why does the block start was `else`?

Comment: @lealand I choose to give Jerome the benefit of the doubt and assume that it's because he tracked down the issue to just those lines, and there's some `if` above it in the actual full code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a typo

Answer (score 6):

You have an extra `(` you don't need. It has nothing to do with the `&&`

```
else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && choice.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
```

You have to have the same number of `)` as you have `(`.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && choice.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
{
activityFactor = 1.6;
}
else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("F") && choice.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))    
{
activityFactor = 1.5;
}
```